# Is there a jQuery unfocus method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I unfocus a textarea or input? I couldn't find a `$('#my-textarea').unfocus();` method?

Comment: also not the jQuery function `.focusout()` that is slightly different from `blur()` http://api.jquery.com/focusout/ , quoting the doc `This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling)`

Answer (score 365, accepted):

```
$('#textarea').blur()
```

Documentation at: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Strange. I am trying to blur() before the window loses focus so that when I come back, the text area is not selected by default. Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: something like $('window').blur(function() {
$('#textarea').blur();
});

Comment: maybe you need to blur the text area on window focus then?

Comment: may be you are trying to bind the event before the DOM is loaded. Try to put the code in the ready handler of the page like this:
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#textarea').blur()
})

Comment: works great with `$('#textarea').bind('blur', function() ...)` also

Answer (score 14):

Based on your question, I believe the answer is how to *trigger a blur*, not just (or even) set the event:

```
 $('#textArea').trigger('blur');
```

Comment: This answer made more sense to me. I wanted to know how to un-highlight or make my text input un-focused. I knew .blur() existed but I didn't really understand the correct syntax for this usage. +1

Comment: Without parameters, `.blur()` is a shortcut for `.trigger("blur")` http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 9):

Guess you are looking for [`.focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Comment: -1 `focusout` is fired only after an input is already started to lose focus. The questioner wants to put an element in that state soa callback handler will do him no good https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusout http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: I was looking for this method and this was the first google result for "jquery select unfocus"

Answer (score 4):

I like the following approach as it works for all situations:

```
$(':focus').blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
// Document click blurer
$(document).on('mousedown', '*:not(input,textarea)', function() {
    try {
        var $a = $(document.activeElement).prop("disabled", true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $a.prop("disabled", false);
        });
    } catch (ex) {}
});
```

Answer (score -15):

So you can do this

```
$('#textarea').attr('enable',false)
```

try it and give feedback

Comment: It will disable the text area, not unfocus it.