# What event should i use to check when an input box loses focus in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that is executed when a textbox gains focus and another function when it loses focus. problem is i dont know where to attach the function for the lost focus event. For the focus i am using

```
 $(" :input[class='Txtbox']").focus(function(){
        $(this).val("");

    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Unfocus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857245/jquery-unfocus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `blur` event.

```
$(" :input[class='Txtbox']").blur(function(){
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(" :input[class='Txtbox']").blur(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `blur()` event. See http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `blur' event handler. Then in the callback do anything you want (i'm sure you that already):

```
$(" :input[class='Txtbox']").blur(function(){
    // Do Something...
});
```