# jquery don't (or remove) focus on any form field

Tags: jquery, html, input, focus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Unfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857245/jquery-unfocus)

Have a form with just one password field tag, and as I use palceholder, I don't want to have automatic input focus. How can I set no focus at all within jquery?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: I don't understand. So the user should not be able to input anything in this field?

Comment: Is Im using it in combination with the simplemodal plugin (a lightbox) it might causes some issues... I try now to trigger a click event on another part on the view... Hope that might work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not fully clear on what you need, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$("input").blur();
```

That will remove the focus from any `input` element that may have it.

Comment: Is Im using it in combination with the simplemodal plugin (a lightbox) it might causes some issues... I try now to trigger a click event on another part on the view... Hope that might work.

Comment: actually in my case it wasn't the help, but I'm sure it is the right solution to a normal case. with simplemodal, there is a param where you can turn of this automatic focus... I just didn't read the instructions properly... Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Since this answer assumes jquery, you only care to blur the input that has focus.  So instead do: ``$('input:focus').blur();``

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the field. `$('input.my-input').attr('disabled', true);` Then re-enable it when you want to allow input (on click or whatever). You'd have to use some CSS (`.my-input:disabled { ... }`) to make sure the browser doesn't grey it out.